# Pandas: sum of values in one dataframe based on the group in a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe such contains companies with their sectors

```
  Symbol             Sector
0    MCM             Industrials
1    AFT             Health Care
2    ABV             Health Care
3    AMN             Health Care
4    ACN  Information Technology
```

I have another dataframe that contains companies with their positions

```
  Symbol  Position
0    ABC  1864817
1    AAP -3298989
2    ABV -1556626
3    AXC  2436387
4    ABT   878535
```

What I want is to get a dataframe that contains the aggregate positions for sectors. So sum the positions of all the companies in a given sector. I can do this individually by

```
df2[df2.Symbol.isin(df1.groupby('Sector').get_group('Industrials')['Symbol'].to_list())]
```

I am looking for a more efficient pandas approach to do this rather than looping over each sector under the group_by. The final dataframe should look like the following:

```
     Sector                  Sum Position
0    Industrials             14567232
1    Health Care            -329173249
2    Information Technology -65742234
3    Energy                  6574352342
4    Pharma                  6342387658
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what your expected output dataframe should look like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, one way to do it is joining both data frames and then group by sector and sum the position column, like so:

```
df_agg = df1.join(df2['Position']).drop('Symbol', axis=1)
df_agg.groupby('Sector').sum()
```

Where, df1 is the df with Sectors and df2 is the df with Positions.

Comment: Will do. I'll wait a day to see if there are other answers that may be an improvement. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

You can `map` the Symbol column to sector and use that Series to group.

```
df2.groupby(df2.Symbol.map(df1.set_index('Symbol').Sector)).Position.sum()
```

Comment: Nice one liner!

Answer (score 4):

let us just do `merge`

```
df2.merge(df1,how='left').groupby('Sector').Position.sum()
```

Comment: Yes I also went with -- pd.merge(df2, df1, on="Symbol").groupby('Sector')['Position'].sum().reset_index()